# How to change color of track and thumb on Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to change the color of the track default to green while having the slider thumb be grey.  I tried using value_track_color but that only changes the color of the track when the slider thumb is moved.

```
                    min: 1
                    max: 100
                    step: 1
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    on_value: root.cursor_sen(*args)
                    value_track: False
                    value_track_color: 0.365, 0.761, 0.118, 1
```

[Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itBYB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use the `background_vertical` property, which is just an image of the vertical slider track. The default value is in the `defaulttheme` atlas, and is an image (37 x 41 pixels) that is used as a `BorderImage`. The `defaulttheme` atlas is in the file`/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/kivy/data/images/defaulttheme-0.png` on my Ubuntu box.